# Window scroll(), scrollTo(), scrollBy() not working on popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a new popup window and I want to scroll my page to specific location, I tried all three methods I mentioned on top but none of them is not working.

Here is my code

```
var w = window.open('','TEST','width='+divWidth+',height='+divHeight+'');

w.onload = function() {
    w.scroll(200,300);
};
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you verified the onload event is firing at all?

Comment: Yes I did. I originally have console.log there but I deleted here

Answer (score 0):

Gokhan, my guess is that the window's body is empty, yielding a content size of zero. Since the dimensions of the content are 0 width by 0 height, the window's viewport effectively collapses to nothing -- essentially reducing `scroll()` (and friends) to a noop.

I put together a little fiddle to demonstrate that having sufficient content fixes the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/blangenfeld/SXnA8/3/

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Okay, now I understand that you're creating a pop-up using content from a same-origin page. Try defining an `onload` for the pop-up window and doing your scrolling there.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Just ensuring the size of the content for demo purposes */
            body { min-width: 500px; min-height: 500px;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showPopUp(url) {
                popUp = window.open(url, "_blank", "width=300, height=300");
                /* This works if the URL doesn't violate same-origin policy */
                popUp.onload = function() {
                    this.scrollTo(100, 100);
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Pop-up test</h1>

        <a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="showPopUp('popup.html');">
            Click for a same-domain pop-up
        </a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="showPopUp('http://www.google.com');">
            Click for a google.com pop-up
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your answer. Body is not actually empty, I am opening a URL in real code.
I updated and put an example for Google :  http://jsfiddle.net/SXnA8/5/

Comment: I think it matters whether the popup URL is from the same host as the opening page. Otherwise, your call to `scroll()` et al will be ignored by most browsers due to the same-origin policy.

Comment: That's right. Google example was a stupid example. Same-origin-policy shouldn't restrict my page on localhost, am i right? basically I have a page `http://localhost/main` and in same page i am opening popup window same URL again `http://localhost/main`